# Объявление типа функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Необходимо объявить параметризованную функцию с 2 аргументами, которая возвращает тип первого параметра, если он имеет тип `double` или `float`, а иначе - тип второго параметра. Почему этот код выдаёт ошибку?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using BinaryType = std::function<std::conditional<
                                   std::is_floating_point<T1>::value,
                                   T1, T2>::type (T1, T2)>;
```

Comment: @Abyx 
1) T1 и T2 - недопустимое использование типа в выражении ...
2) недопустимый аргумент шаблон для "_Fty", требуется тип

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А добавлять `typename` кто будет - Страуструп? :)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using BinaryType = std::function<typename std::conditional<
                                 std::is_floating_point<T1>::value,
                                 T1, T2>::type (T1, T2)>;
```

Ну, или так, если реализация позволяет:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using BinaryType = std::function<std::conditional_t<
                                 std::is_floating_point<T1>::value,
                                 T1, T2> (T1, T2)>;
```